# React Swiper Property 'slidesPerView' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

I'm using React, Typescript and Swiper. I'm also on Shopify Hydrogen  with server components. Which maybe preventing the files from finding the type definitions because creating a new Typscript app and installing Swiper doesn't have this issue.

Running `"swiper": "^8.4.5",` `react": "^18.2.0",` `"@shopify/hydrogen": "^1.6.0",`

`Property 'slidesPerView' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<SwiperRef> & SwiperProps'`

It's not just slidesPerView, but other props as well.

Is there anything else I need to install?
I ran `yarn add swiper`

my component looks like.

```
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide, SwiperRef} from 'swiper/react'

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css'

return (
    <Swiper
      ref={swiperRef}
      slidesPerView={3}
      spaceBetween={30}
    >
      {slides.map((slide) => {
        return (
          <SwiperSlide key={slide.id}>
            <Image ... />
          </SwiperSlide>
        )
      })}
    </Swiper>
```

Comment: It's working for me in Create React App with your version of Swiper and React 18.

Comment: You're right, it works fine when I created a new app using create react app. I'm specifically using Shopify Hydrogen  with server components. Which maybe causing the issue. I'll update my question. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there a solution on this case? I tried almost all the solutions but non of them worked. I'm working on create-react-app --template typescript. When I was working without --template typescript there was no problem like this.

Update:
I SOLVED the problem. I downgraded the swiper from v10.0.4 to v9.4.1 and type problems gone. higher versions from v9.4.1 has these type problems. So I advise you guys to use lower versions of swiper.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution to this problem. As discussed in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6843) the problem is the version of TypeScript. If you are under 5.1.6 version (I think is under 5) Swiper throw that error.

HOW TO FIX IT: Update TypeScript to 5.1.6 or above.

Comment: Had a similiar issue with the property "grabCursor", this solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

it's about versions!

i decrease my swiper version to 9.4.1 and type script version to 5.2.2 and fixes issue,

hope helpful

Answer (score 0):

write this to SwiperProps in swiper.react.d.ts file

```
slidesPerView:number,
spaceBetween:number,
pagination:{clickable:boolean},
modules:SwiperModule[]
```

Answer (score 0):

**It resolved my issue without downgrading to v9 of swiper**

```
 npm i @types/swiper
```

or

```
yarn add @types/swiper
```

This is a stub types definition for @types/swiper (https://swiperjs.com).

swiper provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/swiper installed!  [reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/swiper)